# GARCH model with t-innovations

Tags: distributions, residuals, garch, kernel-smoothing

I am modelling a time series with GARCH model with t-distributed error using RUGARCH package. My model is specified as:

`spec = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)),mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), include.mean=TRUE),
                  distribution.model = "std")

fitGARCH_T = ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = X3)`

However when checking the standardized residuals, the plot of the kernel distribution seems to not fit well the t-distribution with the specified degrees of freedom. I use the code below to extract residuals:

`residT=residuals(fitGARCH,standardize = T)`

The plot of the density against the t-distribution with 3 degrees of freedom looks like 
  [image]

What could I conclude from the residuals and what would be the next step if I want to improve the fitting?